# WYSIWYG editor custom class

Tags: 2sxc

Is there a way to add custom formats and classes to the default html formatting of the WYSIWYG editor on 2sxc?  If so could you point me to where to this on 2sxc.

I know TinyMCE is capable of this, I'm just not sure where I should include the code in 2sxc for the custom formatting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (v 9.x) this is not possible. It also won't be added to V9 because V10 will replace the edit dialog with a new Angular 6 solution, so these kinds of features (wysiwyg customization, etc.) will then be looked at again.